# GEB - find and count all elements with specific word in text

Tags: automated-tests, geb

So, I am pretty new to this language and I've got specific task to find and count all specific words withing  tag in search page in google. 
So i managed to open, and find it but I can't find any way to move futher. 
My code:

```groovy
class GoogleUiSpec extends GebSpec {
    def "checking for word"() {
        given: " Search for word 'ebay' in google"
        go "https://www.google.pl/"

        $("body").find("input", name: "q").value("ebay")
        $("center").$("input", 0, name: "btnK").click()
        waitFor { title.endsWith(" Szukaj w Google")}

        $("h3").findAll{ it.has("ebay")}
    }
}
```

This run smoothly but I am almost sure that it's wrong and I have no idea how to move on to count these elements. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If anyone also have some good sources to learn geb(I am currently reading documentation but I can't find solution to this problem) i would appreciate if he could send it to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close!  You can do the following to retrieve the count where h3 contains the word "ebay" and assert the correct number appear:

```groovy
def "checking for word"() {
    given: " Search for word 'ebay' in google"

    go "https://www.google.pl/"

    $("body").find("input", name: "q").value("ebay")
    $("center").$("input", 0, name: "btnK").click()
    waitFor { title.endsWith(" Szukaj w Google")}

    then: "Correct results are show"

    $("h3").count { it.text().toLowerCase().contains("ebay") } == 10
}
```

Note the `toLowerCase()` as most results return as "eBay" and won't match "ebay".

I'd recommending looking into page objects, and creating a GoogleHomePage and GoogleResultsPage something similar to:

```groovy
import geb.Page

class GoogleHomePage extends Page {

    static url = "http://www.google.com"

    static at = {
        logo.displayed
    }

    static content = {
        logo { $("#hplogo") }
        searchField { $("body").find("input", name: "q") }
        searchButton { $("center").$("input", 0, name: "btnK") }
    }

    ResultsPage searchFor(String search) {
        searchField.value(search)
        searchButton.click()

        browser.at(ResultsPage)
    }
}
```

Results page:

```groovy
import geb.Page

class ResultsPage extends Page {

    static at = { title.endsWith(" Szukaj w Google") }

    static content = {

        results { $("h3") }
    }

    def countResultsContaining(String expectedResultPhrase) {
        results.count { it.text().toLowerCase().contains(expectedResultPhrase) }
    }
}
```

Then your test ends up looking a lot cleaner without all the selectors etc, and you have some reusable code for other tests:

```groovy
class GoogleSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "checking for word"() {
        given: " Search for word 'ebay' in google"

        def searchPhrase = "ebay"
        def googlePage = to GoogleHomePage

        when: "I search for ebay"

        def resultsPage = googlePage.searchFor(searchPhrase)

        then: "Correct results are shown"

        resultsPage.countResultsContaining(searchPhrase) == 10
    }
}
```

As for resources, the [Geb Manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) is good, but Geb is written in Groovy - so searching for how to do it using Groovy rather than Geb will aid you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, they also work but i managed to do it another way so I am posting it here. The line which do the trick:

```groovy
println $(By.className("LC20lb")).findAll {it.text().contains("ebay")}.size()
```

Comment: I think it is a matter of courtesy to accept and upvote the other answer as it is correct and contains a full test case and extra information, not just a one-line snippet like yours.

Comment: Emm yea, of course, that's why I've upvoted that answer(but I have <15 rep so you don't see it). 
Where did I wrote that my answer is better? It's just another answer...jeez...

Comment: You are new here, no problem, I will explain: a) Nowhere I said you thought your answer was better. b) I said "**accept** and upvote", but you still have not accepted the answer. This can only be done by the question's author, i.e. by you. You click on the little grey check-mark and make it green, effectively marking the answer as correct and thus closing the question. Some people search for unanswered questions in their field of expertise in order to help, which is how I came here in the first place, only to have to read the whole question & answers just to find out it was already answered.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry for not doing this I am going to accept immediately. Thanks for calm explanation.